# One-Way Repeated ANOVA, check assumptions or not?

Tags: anova, assumptions

I am working on a paper now where statistics is my weak spot and I need some help from experienced statisticians.

I decided to use one-way repeated ANOVA to analyze my results. The following is dummy data that follows a similar data structure as my own results.

[image]

One thing really bugs me a lot is that the ANOVA's assumptions are always hard to meet. Do I always have to check all the assumptions before using ANOVA in my paper? Could I just directly use the one-way repeated ANOVA to analyze my outputs? I need some valuable opinions here. Thanks.

Comment: What assumptions of ANOVA are violated in your data? An more robust alternative to RM ANOVA is a linear mixed model regression/multilevel regression with mouse as random effect and time as predictor.

Comment: 1. The responses for each factor level have a normal population distribution (violation sometimes);
2. These distributions have the same variance (violation sometimes);
3. The data are independent (this one always meets)

Comment: To get some good advice, you want to describe how you are checking these assumptions and what the output was.  It is *very* common for people to not understand the assumptions of these models, and therefore to use inappropriate methods.

Comment: Agree with needing to see how you tested the assumptions and the output. ANOVA can usually handle small deviations from normality and homoscedasticity, but what constitutes as "small" is debatable. Also size of your dataset matters. But I suggest you look into multilevel regression as an alternative.